# Echo output from commands in a batch file to the cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the following commands inside a batch file:

```
initialize.exe

go run main.go
```

Both `initialize.exe` and `go run` commands output some data, when invoked directly from the command line. When i invoke the batch file from the command prompt, i'm not seeing any output. Is it possible to get the same output as if i were invoking those commands without the batch file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force the display to the console window append >CON to your lines.

For example:

```
Initialize.exe > con
go run main.go > con
```